# Nativescript vue navigateTo outside tab

Tags: vue.js, redirect, nativescript, logout

I'm new to Nativescript Vue. I have Login page and then page with BottomNavigation tabs. When I try to logout from Profile Tab I'm not able to navigateTo login page. It opens login page inside the tab.

On app load it opens Login. When user login he is redirected to App.vue where are tabs. And I need to logout and redirect inside tab.

How can I open login page not inside tab?

Login.vue

```
<template>
    <Page>
        <FlexboxLayout class="page">
            <StackLayout class="form">
                <Image class="logo" src="~/assets/images/logo.png" />

                <StackLayout class="input-field" marginBottom="25">
                    <TextField class="input"
                               hint="E-mail"
                               keyboardType="email"
                               autocorrect="false"
                               autocapitalizationType="none"
                               v-model="user.email"
                               returnKeyType="next"
                               fontSize="18"
                    />
                    <StackLayout class="hr-light" />
                </StackLayout>

                <StackLayout class="input-field" marginBottom="25">
                    <TextField ref="password"
                               class="input"
                               hint="Password"
                               secure="true"
                               v-model="user.password"
                               :returnKeyType="'done'"
                               fontSize="18"
                    />
                    <StackLayout class="hr-light" />
                </StackLayout>

                <Button :text="'Log In'"
                        @tap="submit"
                        class="btn btn-primary m-t-20"
                />
                <Label text="Forgot your password?"
                       class="login-label"
                       @tap="forgotPassword"
                />
            </StackLayout>
        </FlexboxLayout>
    </Page>
</template>
```

App.vue

```
<template lang="html">
    <Page>
        <ActionBar>
            <NavigationButton visibility="collapsed"></NavigationButton>
            <StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
                <Image src="~/assets/images/test.png"></Image>
                <Label text="Telematics"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </ActionBar>

        <BottomNavigation>
            <TabStrip>
                <TabStripItem class="navigation__item">
                    <Label text="Tracking"></Label>
                    <Image src.decode="font://&#xf124;" class="fas t-36"></Image>
                </TabStripItem>
                <TabStripItem class="navigation__item">
                    <Label text="Browse"></Label>
                    <Image src.decode="font://&#xf1ea;" class="far t-36"></Image>
                </TabStripItem>
                <TabStripItem class="navigation__item">
                    <Label text="Profile"></Label>
                    <Image src.decode="font://&#xf007;" class="fas t-36"></Image>
                </TabStripItem>
            </TabStrip>

            <TabContentItem>
                <Frame>
                    <Items />
                </Frame>
            </TabContentItem>

            <TabContentItem>
                <Frame>
                    <Browse />
                </Frame>
            </TabContentItem>

            <TabContentItem>
                <Frame>
                    <Profile />
                </Frame>
            </TabContentItem>

        </BottomNavigation>
    </Page>
</template>
```

Profile.vue

```
<template lang="html">
    <Page actionBarHidden="true">
        <GridLayout class="page__content">
            <Label class="page__content-placeholder"
                   v-if="getEmail"
                   :text="getEmail"
            ></Label>
            <Label class="page__content-icon fas" text.decode="&#xf007;"></Label>
            <Button :text="'Log Out'"
                    @tap="logout"
                    class="btn btn-primary m-t-20"
            />
        </GridLayout>
    </Page>
</template>
```

Logout method

```
logout() {
                this.tryLogout()
                    .then(() => {
                        console.log('LOGING OUT...');
                        this.$navigateTo(Login, {
                            clearHistory: true
                        });
                    })
                    .catch(() => {
                        this.alert("An error occured!");
                    });

            },
```

Comment: Pass the root frame id in the option params of `$navigateTo` method - https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/elements/components/frame/#multiple-frames

Comment: @Manoj but I dont have root frame. My root is Login.vue and there I have only Page

Comment: You must have a Frame in your main or app js file. You can not load a Page without a frame. So login page should have a frame above it, you must assign an id to that frame and navigate on the same. If you still have issues, please share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: Thank you it's finally working. I didn't know how to set ID to first frame in app.js...

Comment: @general666 kindly post how you solved this. I'm having the sae problem. Thank you

Comment: @ManuElMagak check answer bellow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to specify frame in navigateTo:

```
this.$navigateTo(Login, {
   frame: 'main',
   clearHistory: true
});
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I'm nesting the whole on my App.vue `<Page>` in a `<Frame id='main'>` which is working, but on `$navigateBack({frame: 'main-app' })` the page cannot scroll and images don't show(Navigating from Login.vue back to App.vue).
Where are you setting the main frame from, maybe this could help.

Comment: When you navigate "to" and "from" a page, you have to navigate within a frame. So if your frame id is set to `main`, make sure to pass value for the frame option.